# Custom event for jQuery's .on function

Tags: jquery

I want do some actions on `mousedown` (not `click`), but only if left mouse button is pressed.

How i do it:

```
$(document)
    .on('mousedown', '.object', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 1) { // check for left mouse button
             doSomeActions();
        }
    );
```

How i want it to be done:

```
$(document)
    .on('leftClick', '.object', doSomeActions);
```

Is there any way to make it possible?

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: @karaxuna How create `leftClick` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function onLeftClick(fn){
    return function(e){
        if(e.which == 1)
            fn.call(this, e);
    };
}
```

Example:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.object', onLeftClick(doSomeActions));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Love this method